# Unable to embed multiple images in mongoid with carrierwave with polymorphic image model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, nested-forms, carrierwave

I am having difficulty using carrierwave together mongoid. I am writing an application that requires images to be stored in a number of collections, so I have created the Image class as follows (please excuse the use of imageable):

```
class Image
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :imageable, polymorphic: true

  mount_uploader :file, ImageUploader
end
```

`ImageUploader` is as created by `rails generate uploader Image`.

Then I have a story model:

```
class Story
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, :type => String
  field :content, :type => String
  field :category, :type => String

  embeds_many :blog_images, as: :imageable
end
```

When I try to create a `Story` object, i get the error `uninitialized constant BlogImage` even if I do not supply and image through the form. I have also tried in the console to call `story.blog_images << Image.new` with the same error.

In my gem file I have:

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave-mongoid', :require => 'carrierwave/mongoid'
```

My versions are Mongoid - 2.4.7 and carrierwave - 0.6.2.

My main question is how to fix this error, but I am also not too sure about how to set up the form to receive these images. (Ideally I'd like to use javascript to add a new dialog, each time a file is selected.) Is there something wrong with the way I have set up my models or am using carrierwave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify the target class for blog_images because it cannot be derived from the name of the relation. Try:

```
embeds_many :blog_images, as: :imageable, :class_name => 'Image'
```

Comment: This solved the problem I described. In addition I would like to note that the line needs to read `embeds_many :blog_images, as: :imageable, :class_name => 'Image', cascade_callbacks: true` because of [this issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/issues#issue/81)